# Mysql statement syntax error with truncate and alter

Tags: mysql, database

This is probably very simple but why cant i run this script? Gat a syntax error appear. If i run these separate it works, why?

```
    TRUNCATE TABLE table1;
    ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 25;
```

**error**

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL TRUNCATE TABLE table1; ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 25; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 25' at line 1
```

Comment: The syntax error is *what* exactly?

Comment: How are you executing this? It looks like you're trying to run two statements through a tool that doesn't support it.

Comment: @tadman on a mysql database server? fails on php too, could it be my version?

Comment: No, *how* are you executing the query? What tool are you using to run the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will work only if you execute it one after another

i.e.

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE table1;
```

and then

```
ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 25;
```

don't execute together.

if you execute it together first query executed, but second will raise an error.

Comment: actually when truncate is executed auto_increment reset to 1 and same time if you alter to auto_increment it rejects. so always use separately